# How to split a string with whitespace chars at the beginning?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Quick example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "   a b";
        String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");
        for (String s : arr)
            System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I want the array arr to contain 2 elements: "a" and "b", but in the result there are 3 elements: "" (empty string), "a" and "b". What should I do to get it right?

Comment: [`trim()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of a cheat, but replace:

```
String str = "   a b";
```

with

```
String[] arr = "   a b".trim().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: Alternatively (not a cheat): String arr[] = str.trim().split("\\s+")

Answer (score 2):

The other way to trim it is to use look ahead and look behind to be sure that the whitespace is sandwiched between two non-white-space characters,... something like:

```
String[] arr = str.split("(?<=\\S)\\s+(?=\\S)");
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't trim the leading spaces, giving this result:

```
   a
b
```

but nor should it as `String#split(...)` is for splitting, not trimming.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to use `trim()` to remove leading (and trailing) whitespace before the `split(...)` call.

You can't do this with just `split(...)`.  The split regex is matching string *separators*; i.e. there will necessarily be a substring (possibly empty) before and after each matched separator.

You can deal with the case where the whitespace is at the end by using `split(..., 0)`.  This discards any trailing empty strings.  However, there is no equivalent form of `split` for discarding leading empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trimming, you could just add an if  to check if a string is empty or not.